# Mathematica 9 cannot solve a difference equation that Mathematica 8 can

Tags: bugs, version-9, difference-equations

**Bug introduced in 9.0.1 and fixed in 10.0.0**

---

Consider

```
RSolve[{a[n + 1] == 2 a[n] + n (1 + 2^n), a[1] == 1}, a[n], n]
```

*Mathematica* 8 can solve this quickly, but *Mathematica* 9, even after being allowed to run for a long time, cannot give a result.

Comment: Strange, but this works : `RSolve[{a[n + 1] == 2 a[n] + b[n], a[1] == 1}, a[n], n] /. 
 b[m_] -> m (1 + 2^m)`.

Comment: I can confirm this behavior and think it is a bug. I have sent WRI tech support a report of this problem. I will post their answer when I receive it.

Comment: @m_goldberg C'mon! [It's clearly a feature!](http://geekwhisperin.files.wordpress.com/2009/09/bug-vs-feature.jpg)

Comment: Sometimes internal functionality gets improved by making it more flexible, but in the course of doing so a good hard-coded algorithm that solves a specific problem gets broken.

Answer (score 3):

I submitted a report about this problem  to WRI tech support. I have received their reply and quote it part below.

> Thank you for bringing this RSolve issue to our attention.
>
> I can reproduce the situation you found on both Mathematica 9 and Mathematica prerelease and have filed a report on it.

I think it is safe to tag this question with [bugs](/questions/tagged/bugs).